# Data between two activities Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I read similar questions and tried to figure out how to use the code because I'm new in kotlin. I always get an error and the info that I received is null always. I tried this code.

```
  val intent:Intent = Intent(this, RecibirDatos::class.java)
  intent.putExtra("nombre", binding.ptNombre.text)
  startActivity(intent)
```

And in the other activity:

```
 val extras = intent.extras
 if (extras != null) { val value: String? = extras.getString("nombre")}
```

Comment: There is no problem with this code

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this in the second line while passing data;

```
intent.putExtra("nombre", binding.ptNombre.text.toString())
```

Comment: omg im so idiot, of course is it. I forget add toString(). Next time i wont fail like that, thanks.

Comment: happens to everyone :D